# Basic method chaining

Tags: python, method-chaining

I found this [method chaining in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172934/method-chaining-in-python), but even with it I couldn't understand method chaining in Python.

Here the goals are two: solve the coding problem and understand method chaining (given that I am still not 100% confident with callables).

Down to the problem definition.

I want a class that has two methods: one sets a parameter of the object = 'line' and the other overwrites to 'bar'.

This is what I got so far:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, kind=None):
        self.kind = kind

    def __call__(self, kind=None):
        return foo(kind=kind)

    def my_print(self):
        print (self.kind)

    def line(self):
        return self(kind='line')
    def bar(self):
        return self(kind='bar')
```

Sadly, with this code I can achieve my goal doing this

```
a = foo()
a.bar().line().bar().bar().line().my_print()
```

But I would like to obtain the same result by writing this code

```
a = foo()
a.bar.line.bar.bar.line.my_print()
```

How do I achieve this? I guess is something wrong in how I defined the `__call__` method. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Method chaining is simply being able to add `.second_func()` to whatever `.first_func()` returns. It is fairly easily implemented by ensuring that all chainable methods return `self`. (Note that this has nothing to do with `__call()__`).

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, kind=None):
        self.kind = kind
    def my_print(self):
        print (self.kind)
        return self
    def line(self):
        self.kind = 'line'
        return self
    def bar(self):
        self.kind='bar'
        return self
```

You can use `foo` objects in a non-chained way by ignoring their returned values:

```
a = foo()
a.line()
a.my_print()
a.bar()
a.my_print()

assert a.kind == 'bar'
```

Or, since every function now returns the object itself, you can operate
directly on the returned value. You can use method chaining with this equivalent code:

```
b = foo()
b.line().my_print().bar().my_print()
assert b.kind == 'bar'
```

Or even:

```
c = foo().line().my_print().bar().my_print()
assert c.kind == 'bar'
```

The question of getting rid of the `()` calling syntax is a *completely separate concept* from method chaining. If you want chain properties, and have those properties mutate their object, use the `@property` decorator. (But mutating objects via a property seems dangerous. Better to use a method and name it with a verb: `.set_line()` instead of `.line`, for example.)

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, kind=None):
        self.kind = kind
    def my_print(self):
        print (self.kind)
        return self
    @property
    def line(self):
        self.kind = 'line'
        return self
    @property
    def bar(self):
        self.kind='bar'
        return self

a = foo()
a.line
a.my_print()
a.bar
a.my_print()

assert a.kind == 'bar'

b = foo()
b.line.my_print().bar.my_print()
assert b.kind == 'bar'

c = foo().line.my_print().bar.my_print()
assert c.kind == 'bar'
```

Comment: @Rob Thanks ! as it always return `self` , how can we return data at last chain. in this case `return .kind`

Comment: @Akhilesh Perhaps like: `b.line.my_print().bar.my_print().kind`.

Comment: just to help out people like me searching if we can improve the formatting of the chain of methods to improve the readability : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4768979

Answer (score 10):

Use properties (descriptors).

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, kind=None):
        self.kind = kind

    def __call__(self, kind=None):
        return foo(kind=kind)

    def my_print(self):
        print (self.kind)

    @property
    def line(self):
        return self(kind='line')

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self(kind='bar')
```

Note, though, that you overwrite nothing, the modification doesn't work inplace (which is arguably good, btw). Anyway, this doesn't look like a good design choice for most real-world cases, because at some point your methods will require arguments.

Answer (score 0):

ther's an another interesting way of achieving this

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, kind=[]):
        self.kind = kind

    def __getattr__(self, attrs):
        self.attrs = attrs
        return Foo(self.kind + [attrs]) 

    def __call__(self):
        return self.kind[::-1][0]


my_obj = Foo()
print(my_obj.bar.line.bar.bar.line())
```

with this code u don't have to pass `.my_print()` but one thing to note here is the Foo class will take anything as argument like if we try `print(my_obj.bar.line.bar.bar.circle())` it will return circle.

You can also edit this code to take the args while calling any function.