# Calling class/ object methods in sequence

Tags: python

Is there a way to call class/ object methods in a sequence without writing every time the "class.method" or "object.method"?

```
For example:
class ClassAWithALongName():
    @classmethod
    def do_stuff1()

    @classmethod
    def do_stuff2()
    @classmethod
    def do_stuff3()

Instead of:
ClassAWithALongName.do_stuff1()
ClassAWithALongName.do_stuff2()
ClassAWithALongName.do_stuff3()

Is there a way to do it like:
ClassAWithALongName{
                    do_stuff1(),
                    do_stuff2(),
                    do_stuff3()}
```

Comment: Check out method chaining. There are several questions on SO related to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817578/basic-method-chaining

Answer (score 1):

You can store the function objects in a list so that you can iterate through the list to call the function objects instead:

```
routine = [
    ClassAWithALongName.do_stuff1,
    ClassAWithALongName.do_stuff2,
    ClassAWithALongName.do_stuff3
]
for func in routine:
    func()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make it a fluid design, and return the class from each `classmethod`:

```
class ClassAWithALongName:
    @classmethod
    def do_stuff_1(cls):
        # Do stuffs
        return cls

    @classmethod
    def do_stuff_2(cls):
        # Do stuffs
        return cls
```

Now, you can chain the function calls:

```
ClassAWithALongName.do_stuff_1().do_stuff_2()
```

Will this design meet your need, and go along your work is highly dependent on your code.