# python method chaining on methods from a class

Tags: python, oop

I have a created a class like below which takes a pandas data frame and returns aggregate of it and sample of it. I can call each of those methods separately but I am unable to chain them like df.columns.to_list(). How can I make it work?

```
import pandas as pd    
iris = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')




class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df=df
    
    def return_agg(self):
        non_num=self.df.select_dtypes(exclude='number').columns.to_list()
        self.df=self.df.groupby(non_num,dropna=False).sum().reset_index()
        return self.df

    def return_sample(self):
        self.sample=self.df.sample(frac=0.1, replace=True, random_state=1)
        return self.sample
    

a = MyClass(iris)
a.return_sample() #works
a.return_agg() #works
a.return_sample().return_agg() #doesnot work
```

After making the change as suggested by various friends below, the method chaining works but the result is not expected.

```
a = MyClass(iris)
df1=a.return_agg().df
df2=a.return_sample().return_agg().df
df1
[44]:
species sepal_length    sepal_width petal_length    petal_width
0   setosa  250.3   171.4   73.1    12.3
1   versicolor  296.8   138.5   213.0   66.3
2   virginica   329.4   148.7   277.6   101.3
[45]:

df2
[45]:
species sepal_length    sepal_width petal_length    petal_width
0   setosa  250.3   171.4   73.1    12.3
1   versicolor  296.8   138.5   213.0   66.3
2   virginica   329.4   148.7   277.6   101.3
```

df2 should be different from df1 because it is aggregating on sample.

Comment: because `a.return_sample()` doesn't return the object instance it returns `self.sample`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41817688/6083145

Answer (score 0):

In your current implementation, `self.sample` is an instance of `pandas.DataFrame` and not `MyClass`, and since pandas Dataframe doesn't have `return_sample` method, its obvious that it'll return an error. If you create an instance of `MyClass` to store `self.sample`, the provided function calls should work as expected

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def return_agg(self):
        non_num = self.df.select_dtypes(exclude='number').columns.to_list()
        self.df = self.df.groupby(non_num, dropna=False).sum().reset_index()
        return self.df

    def return_sample(self):
        # Instance of MyClass                <----
        self.sample = MyClass(self.df.sample(frac=0.1, 
                                             replace=True, 
                                             random_state=1)
                              )
        return self.sample
```

Talking about chaining that you've mentioned in the question, `columns` in `df.columns.to_list()` is an attribute and is an instance of another class which implementes `to_list()`