# Calling multiple methods of an object in sequence

Tags: python

I need to do something like this:

```
abc = xyz()
abc.method1()
abc.method2()
abc.method3()
...
```

Is there a way to shorten this? Like:

```
abc= xyz()
abc.{method1(),method2(),method3(),...}
```

or something?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that? Your shortened code looks way less readable to me.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve? Do these "methods" explicitly return anything? Maybe you could describe your use-case in more detail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [method chaining in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172934/method-chaining-in-python)

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a shorter way if would ever need it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by ensuring that the instance functions (methods) each return a reference to the instance in which they are running (*self*)

```
class xyz:
    def method1(self):
        print('m1')
        return self
    def method2(self):
        print('m2')
        return self
    def method3(self):
        print('m3')
        return self

abc = xyz()
abc.method1().method2().method3()
```

**Output:**

```
m1
m2
m3
```

**Observation:**

Whilst it can be done, I offer this merely as an answer to the original question. I do not condone the practice

Answer (score 3):

You can call a objects method by string using the `getattr()` function build into python.

```py
class xyz():
    def method0(self):
        print("1")
    
    def method1(self):
        print("2")

abc = xyz()

# use this if you have numbers
for i in range(2):
    getattr(abc, f"method{i}")()

# use this if you have a list of methods   
names = ["method0", "method1"]

for name in names:
    getattr(abc, name)()
```

Answer (score 1):

For a systematic approach and keeping the integrity of the methods use [`methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#methodcaller). Compatible with arguments, see doc.

```
from operator import methodcaller

obj = xyz()

m_names = ['method1', 'method2', 'method3']

for name in m_names:
    print(methodcaller(name)(obj))
```